# sklearn Count vectorizer - how to save, load and use to transform a single text at a later point

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

As usual, I am struggling with conceptualising the fundamentals. I have trained and tested a number of 1v1 estimators on a dataset. The training data is a combination of count_vectorizer and sum of tfidf scores for all the words in the sentence for each estimator (each estimator is for a different classifier and each classifier has a dedicated lexicon).
So the count_vectorizer values stay constant and this is concatenated to an array of scores relevant to a given class for each estimator.

below is a toy example:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words=stopwords)
count_vector = cv.fit_transform(series_of_train_texts.tolist())
test_vector = cv.transform(series_of_test_texts.tolist())

df_train_scores = list(zip(df_train['score_1'], df_train['score_2'], 
                     df_train['score_3']
                     ))

training_array = np.array(df_train_list)
test_array = np.array(df_test_list)

X_train = np.hstack([count_vector.todense(), training_array])
X_test = np.hstack([test_vector.todense(),test_array])

svm_var = LinearSVC(tol=1e-5, max_iter=1500)


for class in groups:
    svm_var.fit(X_train, df_train[class].tolist())
    predictions= list(svm_var.predict(X_test))
```

I have 2 questions:

1. how can I introduce a single test sentence that requires first transforming via the count vectorizer and concatenating with the various tfidf scores before making the prediction?

- if I cv.transform([single_sentence]) and concatenate with an array of scores (1 sent so 1dimensional array) I get a shape mismatch - I can force a re-shape, but I'm not sure why I'd choose a particular shape or why I didn't have to do that in the first place.
  count_vectorizer document matrix is of shape (1, 3455) array of scores shape = (3,).

2. how can I export this to make it reusable

- do I export the count_vectorizer after fit_transform? - if so how do I import it to be able to transform a new sentence? (after exporting count_vector in the code above - joblib.dump and loading again, I can't immediately use transform - do I need both the cv and count_vector - does it need to be that specific one or do I instantiate a new cv?)
- is it one estimator that I export? I don't think so since it's retrained per class in the for loop - so do I have to do that again or do I save each estimator in the loop?

My usual approach to tackling this is to 1) read the docs; 2) google around; 3) try everything I can think of. By the time I get to 3, it's such a painfully long process of trying every possible combination of what I think might work yet without any understanding of how I'm supposed to be thinking about the problem.

Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to persist and reuse a train model is to save it as one object. `Pipeline` in scikit-learn allows you to combine preprocessing step and model into on object. Once you have created your pipeline you can `fit()` it with your train set and then save it using `joblib` as in this toy example:

```
import joblib

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['abcde', 'abcde', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
    'B': [0,0,1,1]}
)

X = df['A']
y = df['B']

model = Pipeline([('countVectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
         ('svc', LinearSVC())])

model.fit(X, y)

joblib.dump(model, 'model.joblib')

model2 = joblib.load('model.joblib')
model2.predict(['abde'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this - there is an additional step that needs to be performed separately - the concatentation of an array of scores: countvectorize > concatenated with an array of scores > input for classifier - is there a way of adding this between the two steps?